# add a start div tag to the element and end div tag to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html structure (refer below)

```
<div class="pagination_info"></div>
<div class="pagination_numbers"></div>
```

Now, what I want is to add a start div tag before the .pagination_info div and add end div tag after the .pagination_numbers div so the expected output must be (refer below)

```
<div class="pagination_wrapper">
    <div class="pagination_info"></div>
    <div class="pagination_numbers"></div>
</div>
```

what I tried so far is (refer below)

```
$('.pagination_info').before('<div class="pagination_wrapper">');
$('.pagination_numbers').after('</div>');
```

so supposedly, what im trying to achieve is to wrap the .pagination_info div and .pagination_numbers with a parent div that has a class name "pagination_wrapper" but sadly unsuccessful yet. Any help, suggestion, recommendation, ideas, clues to make this work will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're thiking in text (HTML), but that's not what you're dealing with. You're dealing with elements in a tree (the DOM). The answers below show you how to work with the elements (jQuery has a function *specifically* for this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery has a [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method:

```
$(".pagination_info, .pagination_numbers").wrapAll("<div class=\"pagination_wrapper\">");
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h4k6tsc0/)

Answer (score 6):

`.wrapAll()` will wrap the two div's around the new div:

```
$(".pagination_info, .pagination_numbers").wrapAll("<div class='pagination_wrapper'>");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y6Lhd3t2/)